# configuring CKEditor pasteFilter to strip out certain inline styles

Tags: ckeditor

My stakeholders are using CKEditor version 4.10.1 in Drupal (8.6.13).

They have a use case where they are often copying from Google Docs and pasting into the WYSIWYG textarea. Google uses inline css properties. Here's a sample:

```
<span style="font-size:36pt;font-family:Merriweather;color:#000000;background-color:transparent;font-weight:700;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;">Your Name</span></p>
```

They often have to change the sizes of text, and also the font face. In the example above, these are `font-size:36pt;font-family:Merriweather;` in the `style` tag.

I am looking at the [pasteFilter](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-pasteFilter) configuration directive. In the example, they show how to filter certain tags, and tags with certain attributes:

```
config.pasteFilter = 'h1 h2 p ul ol li; img[!src, alt]; a[!href]';
```

However, what I want to remove is just certain css styles. For instance, if the paste input is

```
 <span style="font-size:36pt;font-family:Merriweather;vertical-align:baseline;">Hello</span>
```

then I want the source to read

```
 <span style="vertical-align:baseline;">Hello</span>
```

I.e. only `font-size:36pt;font-family:Merriweather;` are removed. (And I want to remove any `font-size` and `font-family` specification.)

Is that possible with `pasteFilter`? If so, how do I express that?

**Edit** whitelist solutions don't meet our acceptance criteria, because my stakeholders want to preserve other directives, such as bold, italics, etc. We don't want to strip *all* the styling, or the entire `span` tag; we only want to remove `font-size` and `font-family`.

Comment: Does that work? `config.disallowedContent = '*{font*}';`

Comment: Plug-in is an option? https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/removeformat.html

Comment: did you try the advanced content filter? 
allowedContent: 'span{vertical-align};'
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/removeformat.html

Comment: @Pat_Morita I'm not sure that's going to work -- I want to allow *everything* except for `font-size` and `font-family`.

Comment: then try this - should do the job: config.disallowedContent = '*{font-family,font-size}';

Comment: @Wizard this seems to strip the entire <span> tag, which is not what I want. I only want to remove font-size and font-family directives

Comment: @Pat_Morita That doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't appear to be filtering anything.

Comment: Please check again. if "\*{font\*};" WORKED but removed too much then my solution should work too. If you only want to remove the font directives in spans and nowhere else do it like so: config.disallowedContent = 'span{font-family,font-size}';

Comment: @Pat_Morita I've checked this several times. It's not working. Are you testing this, or just freehand coding?

Comment: could you please update your question and post your whole config? do you use font plugins?

Comment: @Pat_Morita Sure, I will do that. Before you ask me to check your code a second time, can you check yours at least once?

Comment: Added it to my websites ckeditor config. It works. So I assume another setting in your config deactivated disallowed content like "CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true" or you have a font plugin installed or... or... or... we might continue that in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [How to Allow Everything Except…](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_disallowed_content.html#how-to-allow-everything-except), you can use:

```
config.allowedContent = {
    $1: {
        // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
        attributes: true,
        styles: true,
        classes: true
    }
};
config.disallowedContent = '*{font*}';
// if you want to be more specific: config.disallowedContent = 'span{font-size,font-family}';
```

I tested it and it works, see for yourself in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g7jk8t2/) I've created.

Comment: How would you write this for all styles except text-align? - I need to use div{*} in disallowedContent, but not able to allow text-align in that case